# how to add styles inside nested routes react router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am not able to add the style in my app.js file. The div is not working inside the route. Is there any other way to add style inside the route?

```
<Routes>
  <Route exact path="/" element={auth.token ? <Home > : < Login />} />
  <Route exact path="/register" element={<Register />} />
  <div style={{ marginBottom: "60px" }}>
    <Route element={<PrivateRouter />}>
      <Route exact path="/:page" element={<PageRender />} />
      <Route exact path="/:page/:id" element={<PageRender/>} />
    </Route>
  </div>
</Routes>
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a layout route that renders the div element and style ***and*** an [`Outlet` component](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/components/outlet) for the nested `Route` components to render their `element` prop into.

Example:

```
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const Layout = () => (
  <div style={{ marginBottom: "60px" }}>
    <Outlet />
  </div>
);

export default Layout;
```

...

```
import Layout from '../path/to/Layout';

...

<Routes>
  <Route path="/" element={auth.token ? <Home /> : < Login />} />
  <Route path="/register" element={<Register />} />
  <Route element={<Layout />}>
    <Route element={<PrivateRouter />}>
      <Route path="/:page" element={<PageRender />} />
      <Route path="/:page/:id" element={<PageRender />} />
    </Route>
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

Comment: bro is there any other way to do like in previous we used to add the div inside the route like can we add style inside the route

Comment: @surajprajapati No, not really. `Route` components can only render other `Route` components as children. The alternative is to render `PageRender` on `"/:page/*"` and it renders the styled `div` and another `Routes` component with descendent routes. In RRDv6 `Route` components can't just be rendered wherever you like, they can only be rendered by the `Routes` component or another `Route` component in the case of nested routes.

Comment: **The link is not working I have imported the link from the react-router-dom.
    if I am doing the right click and copy that url and open it another tab then it's working 
    but the click of that it's not working** 
    
    <Link to={`${msg.url}`} className="d-flex text-dark align-items-center">
    <Avatar src={msg.user.avatar} size="big-avatar" />

Comment: @surajprajapati What link are you referring to? There aren't any in the code snippet in this question. Is this a separate issue from the layout route?

Comment: can we connect in zoom I need a help

Comment: Yes that was the separate issue I have fixed that error

Comment: react_devtools_backend.js:4026 Warning: Encountered two children with the same key, `62f0b2da5496a1e6a2a2249d`. Keys should be unique so that components maintain their identity across updates. Non-unique keys may cause children to be duplicated and/or omitted — the behavior is unsupported and could change in a future version.

Comment: here in my mongodb the id keys are different but in these I am getting the error

Comment: @surajprajapati I can't do a zoom call, but if you could fork your code into a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) that reproduces the issue I can take a look when I have availability.

Comment: sure can I get your id or name to search and send the code

Comment: actually I am new in react not that much new but I have middle level of knowledge I was building the instagram clone but my I am getting an error bz of keys.

Comment: so my message part is not working I am getting an undefined in the search bar

Comment: http://localhost:3000/message/undefined                                                                    return navigate(`/message/${user._id}`)

Comment: @surajprajapati These follow-on questions and issue regarding links is off-topic from this post about the layout route, and I can't really debug code I can't see. It would better benefit you to create a new SO post specific to this issue of creating a link target and include a [mcve] and clear details on the issue including steps to reproduce it.